# Accessing historical likes data via Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am accessing Facebook FanPage-Data via the Facebook SDK with PHP. Everything works fine so far, but I am missing one crucial thing:

The number of fans a site had when a post was posted. (Reason: If I want to calculate how good the interaction rate was I need not the current number of fans but the number of fans when the post was posted originally).

With /{PageName}/ I can access the "Likes", but these are the current number of likes=fans for the Page.

With /{PostID}/likes?summary=true and with /{PostID}/comments?summary=true I get the Number of Likes and Comments and I find the shares directly in /{PostID}/

How can I get the number of likes the page had when the post was posted? Or how can I get the historical number of fans=page likes for a given day?

Comment: It might be in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/insights/

Comment: Thanks, Ceejayoz, but the insights are only available for the own page, not for other FanPages...

Comment: Oh, you're checking pages you don't have access to? I don't believe historical data is available to you. You'll need to fetch the like count when the post is created.

Comment: What I do (eg): I get all the posts from the last year from a fan page (let's say cocacola). But if the fanpage grows fast 10 likes for post in January might have been ok while 10 likes in December (with lets say 10x the number of fans) is not so good. So I would like to get the number of fans of the day the post was posted as an indication (10 post likes / 100 page fans is than the same quality as 100 posts likes / 1000 page fans)

Comment: As already stated, that info is not available to you for pages that you do not have admin access to.